# Cant import PhoneGap 3.4 project inside Eclipse workspace

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova

I have created phonegap project.And successfully, it is running on AVD. But, when I tried to impport that project inside my eclipse workspace....nothing happened.

Here is the screenshot appering & no action taking place after I clicking finish.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should checked `copy projects in to workspace`.

And make sure your project is properly built into android platforms.

Your final import will be like this on eclipse.

[image]

Hope this will help you !!

Answer (score 1):

don't click on **copy projects in to workspace**  option ,
and don't try to import that project inside my **eclipse workspace drive** .

Answer (score 0):

Check  **copy  projects in to workspace**  and try again